# Jedis: Broken Pipe

Tags: java, database, redis, jedis

So, I have 2 applications using jedis. They both connect to the same server, and one listens for a Publish in order to check if something certain is writen. Well, after about 10 hours of conisistent use and load, setting/getting/pub/sub ect, the jedis returns Broken Pipe. I don't know why because I have the timeout to 0 in jedis. Any ideas?

Comment: anyone have any idea one what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've discovered Jedis keeps open connections to Redis and does not check for the state of these connections. If a connection has been interrupted during idle time (network got reset or momentarily disconnected, or connection timed out), Jedis connection pool will basically become invalid, but Jedis client won't report that until you try to send a command down the pipe. 
Here's the discussion on github: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/185

The way I worked around this is by sending a "ping" before sending any data:

```
private Jedis getResource() {
    Jedis jedis;
    try{
        jedis = pool.getResource();
        jedis.ping();
    } catch (JedisException e) {
        pool.destroy();
        pool = getPool(this.url);
        jedis = pool.getResource();
    }
    return jedis;
}

public String get(EphemeralKey key, EphemeralLocation location) throws Exception {
    String encodedKey = encodeKey(key, location);
    try (Jedis jedis = getResource()) {
        return jedis.get(encodedKey);
    } catch (JedisException e) {
        throw wrapJedisException(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```